# Delegate method is not called (is nil)

Tags: ios, objective-c

EDITED
I have .xib file with `UIView`. `UIView` contains some elements and tap gesture recognizer.

It is connected to `AnnotationView` with outlets. In `AnnotationView`, I am catching tap events and it works fine.

Then I am trying to pass this event to my parent view (`ViewController`), where `AnnotationView` instance was created and added as subview. But my delegate method is not getting called. I don't know, how to solve this problem, and I don't know if it is because I am using subview or I am just doing something wrong with delegate.

Here is some code:

**AnnotationView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol protName <NSObject>

-(void) test;

@end

@interface AnnotationView : UIView

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *accessoryLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <protName> delegate;

-(IBAction)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer;
@end
```

**AnnotationView.m**

```
#import "AnnotationView.h"

@implementation AnnotationView


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AnnotationView"
                                                             owner:self
                                                           options:nil];
        AnnotationView *_myView = [nibContents objectAtIndex:0];
        _myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        [self addSubview: _myView];

    }
    return self;
 }

-(IBAction)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer{
    NSLog(@"tap tap");

    [self.delegate test]; //this delegate is nil
}

@end
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AnnotationView.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <protName>
@property (nonatomic,retain) AnnotationView *annot;

-(void) test;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _annot = [[AnnotationView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 212, 45)];
    _annot.textLabel.text = @"some text";
    _annot.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:_annot];
}
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    _annot.delegate = self;
}
-(void) test{
    NSLog(@"Delegate massage is received!");
}
@end
```

Comment: It's very weird to me that you're loading a UIView subclass, that in turn loads a UIView subclass that is hooked up from a nib, and adding that as a subview. Am I seeing this right?

Comment: I'm new to objective-c and this solution for adding subview i've found  somwhere on stackoverflow and you seeing it right, it works that way... and "tap tap" is the only thing which is working...

Comment: It almost looks recursive, but I don't know if loading from a nib will call `-initWithFrame`

Comment: Edited question. There was a small typo. 'UIView' with labels, image and tap recognizer are created in 'AnnotationView.xib' file, if this matters.

Comment: I don't see the error here. Make sure you're not clearing the `delegate` property.

Comment: I see it now. When you load the initial AnnotationView in `viewDidLoad`, that object, inside its `initWithFrame` method creates another AnnotationView that sets its delegate to `self`. The thing you are tapping on is one of the two AnnotationView objects, and it is intercepting the touch event. My answer is what fixes this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do this:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 212, 45)];
    NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AnnotationView"
                                                         owner:nil
                                                       options:nil];
    for (id object in nibContents) {
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[AnnotationView class]]) {
            _annot = (AnnotationView *)object;
        }
    }        
    _annot.frame = frame;
    _annot.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    _annot.textLabel.text = @"some text";
    _annot.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:_annot];
}
```

Comment: This code gives error '[<ViewController 0x7490330> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key image.'.

Comment: change the `owner:` parameter from `self` to `nil`

Comment: Ok now delegate is working, but i was forced to delete all elements from my .xib file view because the error was still appear. So now i'm gonna solve this new problem. Thank you a lot.

Comment: The second issue was not so difficult so now all works fine. I spent 6 hours to make this code work and You fix it for 5 min. Thank you again!!!

Comment: Glad this fixed it. Hope it clears it up so you understand why it works. It's hard for me to explain why because I am having trouble wrapping my mind around it myself. It makes sense for me to do it this way. I'd also like to point you to a change up in my code, with the `for()` loop

Answer (score 1):

How to use delegate in correct way!

In SecondViewController.h:

```
   @protocol messageDelegate <NSObject>
    @optional
    -(void) test;
    @end
    @interface SecondViewController : NSString
    @property (nonatomic, assign) id <messageDelegate> delegate;
    @end
```

In SecondViewController.m:

```
-(void)readyToSend
{
    [self.delegate test];

}
```

In ViewController.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<messageDelegate>
@end
```

In ViewController.m: in

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
secondViewController.delegate = self;
}
-(void) test{
NSLog(@"Delegate massage is received!");
```

}

Hope it will help!

Comment: Thanx, but it's not the problem. My delegate is exactly like yours except @optional.

Answer (score 0):

It is your viewController not the AnnotationView that implements the  protocol.
So you could move that to give:

```
@interface AnnotationView : UIView <protName>
```

Comment: The ViewController did implement the protocol.

Comment: Yes that's the problem. The delegate for the AnnotationView is called.

Comment: Sorry i don't get your point. My ViewController implements protocol. Adding protocol to AnnotationView doesnt solve the problem...